# Dojo widget that creates a datagrid and populates it

Tags: datagrid, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible in Dojo to create a widget programatically that does an xhr during postCreate and then on response create a data grid and display contents. Attach points in templatestring are allowed, but no markup. The widget can take in a srcNode parameter.

```
onMyCreate(params, srcNode)
{
    // everything happens within in the widget and the display.
    var wdg = new MyWidget(params, srcNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not.  Create store --> xhr to get data --> populate store with data --> create data grid at the attach point passed in giving it reference to that store.  It shouldn't make a difference where you decide to call it as long as the attach point exists and you handle the store correctly.

Comment: The attach point itself should be present in the templateString as  '<div dojoAttachPoint="myAttachPoint"></div>' and not passed in, i.e., the attach point is currently not yet present in the HTML.